# Free C.String() in defer

Tags: go, cgo

If I free `res` in a defer statement, will the result still be successfully copied (without risk of being overwritten)?

```
//export DoSomething
func DoSomething() *C.char {
    s := "some string"
    res := C.CString(s)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(res))
    return res
}
```

I understand that the best practice is to free the memory, but it's unclear to me if the the result is copied before that memory is freed and if there is a risk for the memory to be overwritten.

Comment: The problem is with what you call "the result": `C.CString` calls out to `malloc` of the linked-in `libc` and then copies the contents of its argument into that memory, and then returns _a pointer to_ (an address of) the `malloc`-allocated block. So you then make your function return that pointer and—right before actually returning from the function—make `libc` `free()` the pointed-to memory block—creating a classical "use after free" condition.

Comment: When you work with a language w/o GC—such as C,—you have to think in terms of memory ownership: whoever is the last to work with an allocated memory block is responsible for freeing it. This means `DoSomething` must not deallocate itself what it allocated because the whole point of its existence is to allocate a chunk of memory and return it (for some other parts of the code to use it).

Comment: May be you have just interpreted the suggestion in the `cmd/cgo` to call `C.Free()` in `defer`red blocks way too literally. The doc merely wanted to suggest that using `defer` is the ubuquitous paradigm in Go to free a resource at the end of the currently executing function, but this is all there is to it. With relation to `cgo`, a useful pattern is to use `C.CString` and friends to prepare arguments to call _some other_ C functions passing them these arguments; in this case the pattern is natural: prepare the args→call the function(s)→free the args.

Comment: The problem is when using this with non-c language interpreters like C# for example, I can't go around creating buffers and passing them as args I'm not sure how each language will respond. Sure in C# I might be able to use ref, or out, but what about the next language, it's not very natural.

Comment: I assume the answer is - defer runs before the return statement, so frees the memory, risking memory corruption if the function is used, even if copied immediately.

Comment: But I'm finding it hard to confirm or deny this claim

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The reasoning is simple: 1) `C.CString` and friends is explicitly documented as returning "an unmanaged pointer to unmanaged memory"—if we were to use .NET terms; 2) `defer`s run at the end of the function they are set in. They are defined as running after the `return` caused the function to exit but that is merely a terminological trick—in either case by the time what the function returned is used by code outside the function the `defer`s in the latter had finished executing. 3) `C.Free` frees the memory, not the pointer to it that you're returning.

Comment: One more thing: I'm afraid, you might maintain wrong mental picture for C# as well: neither ref nor out won't do anything to the memory in such a case: they are merely a disguised pointers and have nothing to do with controlling memory lifecycle. When it comes to call C code from .NET using P/Invoke, the runtime can help you by "pinning" managed memory passed to the call during it's lifetime in order for it to not be touched by GC. Go does not implement such pinning in order to have crazy-fast GC in the presence of many concurrently running goroutines.

Comment: …and, well, in Go, it's possible to pass a pointer to a managed memory block to a call to C as long that memory block does not itself contain pointers to Go-allocated memory, as documented in `cmd/cgo`.

Comment: by using  --> SomeFuncInCS(ref string output)
you can use SomeFuncInGo(output **C.Char) which allows a copy by dereference

Comment: There's no such thing as "copy by reference", only "pass by reference": a copy is always a copy. `ref` is a hidden pointer so yes, when you have `fun(ref T v)` and call it, the address of `v` is passed to `fun`, not its contents. But as I've said, this has nothing to do with memory management and lifetime: no amount of indirection by adding more pointers is going to free you from the need to explicitly manage memory which is not managed by the runtime (and its GC) ;-) If this idea does not "click", maybe you should ask another question using different wording.